# Combine collect of list with single value using streams

Tags: java, list, java-8

I have the following data:

```
 CustomClass first = new CustomClass(1, Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
 CustomClass second  = new CustomClass(5, Arrays.asList(6,7,8));
 List<CustomClass> list = Arrays.asList(first, second);
```

Now I want to collect this data into a list that contains the value from `CustomClass` and values from its list.

I want to obtain this: `1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8`

This is what I implemented:

```
list.stream().forEach(item -> {
        result.add(item.value);
        item.values.stream().forEach(seconditem -> result.add(seconditem));
    });
```

I know there's a collect method for stream, but I don't understand how to use it to collect both one value and the list of values from the same class.

Comment: what is value and values for CustomClass ?

Comment: oh sorry, it's Integer and List<Integer>

Comment: If nothing else, you can shorten it to `item.values.stream().forEach(result::add)` or just `result.addAll(item.values())`

Comment: @tobias_k but I want also to add that one value from class to the list

Comment: @sweepserene Sure, I meant you can just shorten that one very long line to that somewhat shorter line. The rest remains the same. Or use `Stream.concat`...

Comment: Does the order of entries in stream matter?

Comment: yes, they have to be in the order i mentioned, value than the values from list

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [`Stream.concat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#concat-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-) to combine a `Stream.of` the single value and the stream of the other values:

```
List<Integer> result = list.stream()
        .flatMap(x -> Stream.concat(Stream.of(x.value), x.values.stream()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```